# wordpress permalink postname 404 on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I am facing a very common issue here hoping someone have the same experience could help me.
The issue is quite normal. I could find plenty issue posts and solutions by search google.

For example: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-permalink-404-issue

But the weird thing is after I delete `#` from

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and also did this part:

I opened up the `httpd.conf` file and found:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride none
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

and changed the `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride all`.

Now it's looking like this:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

but it's still not working.

I'm using WAMP for my localhost and the website works well when I change permalink setting back to default (with post ID).
Here is the `.htaccess` code I'm using.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Did I miss something? Really need your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I Got Answer. It's easy only.

1) Go to WAMP logo in right-bottom of Task-bar of Windows.

2) Click left button

3) then Apache -> Apache Modules

4) Tic(select) the **rewrite_module**

5) that's all.

[For More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/1314503)

Comment: Thanks, but when I went to 3) I cannot find any options like "Apache".

Comment: are you using WAMP which Version?

Comment: Actually It's vertrigoServ 2.29

Comment: then do this as manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2/5758551#5758551

Comment: @JinYou Good. But give that answer. That may useful for others. And if my answer was helped you means, put vote.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to WAMP logo in right-bottom of Task-bar of Windows.

2) Click left button

3) then Apache -> Apache Modules

4) Tic(select) the rewrite_module

5) that's all.

THIS WORKS, THANKS A MILLION.
I spent hours trying to solve this problem, f* ridiculous!
I'm just learning to use wordpress and got completely stuck with a simple thing like adding a page, complete waste of time. Almost decided to use joomla....